# overflow LWC tabs to scroll horizontally

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

[image: ![LWC Tabset component]

When we click on the more button the remaining tabs are coming vertically instead I need to achieve horizontally

[image: Horizontal tab scroll]

[image]

So if i click on the arrow in right tabs have to move horizontally. Is there a way we can achieve in LWC.

Here is my LWC code

```
 <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
    <lightning-tab label="Item One">
        Content for tab 1
    </lightning-tab>   
        <lightning-tab label="Item Two">
            Content for tab 2
        </lightning-tab>        
        <lightning-tab label="Item Three">
            Content for tab 3
        </lightning-tab>        
        <lightning-tab label="Item Four">
            Content for tab 4
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Five">
            Content for tab 5
        </lightning-tab>        
        <lightning-tab label="Item Six">
            Content for tab 6
        </lightning-tab>   
</lightning-tabset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requirement is going to force you to create a custom component.  The `lightning-tabset` base component has [a very limited API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/specification), and this feature isn't an option in that API.

If you like most of what you get with `lightning-tabset`, and don't want to start from scratch, you can refer to the [LWC Base Component Recipes](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/tabset) to learn more about how `lightning-tabset` is put together.